# Change mode-line-buffer-id face for inactive windows

Tags: themes, mode-line

**Is there an Emacs face that can be used to control the colour of inactive buffer names?**

Normally when setting the face `mode-line-buffer-id` all windows are affected.

In this example the `mode-line` has a light background, so I set `mode-line-buffer-id` to a much darker `#333`.

[image: mode-line with dark buffer-id on light background]

The idea is to invert the colour combination for for `mode-line-inactive`.

While this is possible for most of the text in the mode-line of inactive windows, the buffer names becomes unreadable since it's still controlled by the `mode-line-buffer-id` face.

[image: mode-line-inactive with dark buffer-id on dark background]

I believe that setting `mode-line-inactive` to a lighter background would work around the problem, but that's not the result I wish to achieve.

Comment: Here is a link to an example that customizes various aspects of the mode-line:  http://amitp.blogspot.com/2011/08/emacs-custom-mode-line.html

Comment: You can remap a face when the active buffer changes as described here: http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/14658/780

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure whether you're still looking for an answer or not but this was the only result I got on Google while trying to do this myself.

Anyways for whatever reason Emacs calls this `distant-foreground` so the only thing you really need to do is add `:distant-foreground $colour-of-choice` to your face.

Answer (score 1):

This is a variation of the other answers, with this one distinguishing between active and inactive windows.  If a buffer is visible in more than one window, only the active window will have `ml-active-window-face` and the other windows will all have `ml-inactive-window-face`.

```lisp
(defvar ml-selected-window nil)

(defun ml-record-selected-window ()
  (setq ml-selected-window (selected-window)))

(defun ml-update-all ()
  (force-mode-line-update t))

(add-hook 'post-command-hook 'ml-record-selected-window)

(add-hook 'buffer-list-update-hook 'ml-update-all)

(defface ml-active-window-face
   '((t (:foreground "red")))
   "Face for active buffer identification.")

(defface ml-inactive-window-face
   '((t (:foreground "green")))
   "Face for inactive buffer identification.")

(defun ml-propertized-buffer-identification (fmt)
  "Return a list suitable for `mode-line-buffer-identification'.
FMT is a format specifier such as \"%12b\".  This function adds
text properties for face, help-echo, and local-map to it."
  (list (propertize fmt
        'face
          (if (eq ml-selected-window (selected-window))
            'ml-active-window-face
            'ml-inactive-window-face)
        'help-echo
        (purecopy "Buffer name
mouse-1: Previous buffer\nmouse-3: Next buffer")
        'mouse-face 'mode-line-highlight
        'local-map mode-line-buffer-identification-keymap)))

(setq-default mode-line-buffer-identification
  '(:eval (ml-propertized-buffer-identification "%12b")))
```

---

[image: Example]

Answer (score 1):

Here's a variation on another [answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/14658/780) that might help. This example remaps `mode-line-buffer-id` to be green in inactive buffers.

```
(defun toggle-mode-line-buffer-id-face (window)
  "Update the `mode-line-buffer-id' face in WINDOW dependening on
whether the window is selected."
  (with-current-buffer (window-buffer window)
(if (eq (current-buffer) (window-buffer (selected-window)))
    (face-remap-reset-base 'mode-line-buffer-id)
  (face-remap-set-base 'mode-line-buffer-id '(:foreground "green")))))

(add-hook 'buffer-list-update-hook (lambda () (walk-windows #'toggle-mode-line-buffer-id-face nil t)))
```

*Update:*  As noted in the comments, this does not entirely solve the problem. When you have several visible windows visiting the same buffer, they will all share the same face.

Comment: Unfortunately, a buffer can be visible in more than one window, where one could be active and one inactive.

Comment: True, face remapping applies to the buffer and not the window.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it is possible.  It seems that the mode line is updated only when its window is selected (testing using calls to `message` bears this out).  And the code that does this is C code, not Lisp.

You can use a conditional expression in the definition of `mode-line-buffer-identification`, so that the face to use is computed dynamically.  But I don't know of any function or variable that you can use to test whether a given window has an inactive mode-line.

You cannot use `selected-window`, for example, because that always points to the window with the active mode-line.

Here is an example of dynamic updating that is based on the buffer name. It is not what you want, but it at least shows you what you can do.  If you can come up with a way to test whether the window being updated is selected then you could substitute that for the buffer-name test.  (But my impression is that only the selected window gets its mode-line updated.)

```el
(setq-default mode-line-buffer-identification
              '(:eval
                (list (propertize "%b"
                       'face (if ;; NOPE (eq (selected-window) (get-buffer-window (current-buffer)))
                                 (eq (current-buffer) (get-buffer "some-buffer"))
                                 'mode-line-buffer-id
                               'some-other-face)
                       'help-echo "Buffer name mouse-1: Previous buffer\nmouse-3: Next buffer"
                       'mouse-face 'mode-line-highlight
                       'local-map mode-line-buffer-identification-keymap))))
```

---

Another thing you might try is advising function `format-mode-line`.  It does apparently distinguish a window with an active mode-line from one with an inactive mode-line.  But it too is coded in C, so I doubt you will get very far with advising it.  It tests C variable `Qmode_line_inactive`, FWIW.

I'd suggest asking this question on one of the Emacs mailing lists (e.g. `help-gnu-emacs@gnu.org`), if you don't get a satisfactory answer here. Seems like it could be good to be able to do what you request.  +1 for the question, in any case.

Comment: Just to complete Drew's answer, active buffer detection and specific mode-line-buffer-id faces for active and inactive buffers is done in [powerline](https://github.com/milkypostman/powerline). If you want to investigate the code, a good starting point is the function powerline-default-theme defined in [powerline-themes.el](https://github.com/milkypostman/powerline/blob/master/powerline-themes.el#L36)