# Change highlight color when window isn't in focus?

Tags: window, highlighting, focus

I'm using hl-mode as a minor mode for deft. How do I make the highlighted line change color (e.g. to gray) when the deft window isn't the current window, and then back to the default highlight color when the deft window becomes the current window again?

Comment: It turns out there is an option for this, see http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/15141/780.

Answer (score 5):

I've implemented this for `hl-line-mode` using the `buffer-list-update-hook`. 
Here's the code:

```el
(defface hl-line-inactive
  '((t nil))
  "Inactive variant of `hl-line'."
  :group 'hl-line)

(defun hl-line-update-face (window)
  "Update the `hl-line' face in WINDOW to indicate whether the window is selected."
  (with-current-buffer (window-buffer window)
    (when hl-line-mode
      (if (eq (current-buffer) (window-buffer (selected-window)))
          (face-remap-reset-base 'hl-line)
        (face-remap-set-base 'hl-line (face-all-attributes 'hl-line-inactive))))))

(add-hook 'buffer-list-update-hook (lambda () (walk-windows #'hl-line-update-face nil t)))
```

What this code is doing:

- Define a new face `hl-line-inactive` to be used in inactive windows. You can use `M-x customize-face` to modify the attributes of this face to your taste.
- Define a function to temporarily remap the highlighting face in inactive windows. A window is considered inactive if it is not displaying the same buffer as the currently selected window.
- Add a hook to `buffer-list-update-hook` that calls `hl-line-update-face` for all the visible windows.

**Old answer**

The code above (which I'm using in my own `init` file) is much simpler than what I originally posted. Thanks @Drew for the suggestion to use `walk-windows`. I also read more about face remapping (see [Face Remapping](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Face-Remapping.html) in the Emacs Lisp Manual) and realized I could remove a lot of the code.

For posterity, here's what I originally posted:

```el
;; Define a face for the inactive highlight line.
(defface hl-line-inactive
  '((t nil))
  "Inactive variant of `hl-line'."
  :group 'local)

(defun toggle-active-window-highlighting ()
  "Update the `hl-line' face in any visible buffers to indicate which window is active."
  (let ((dups))
    (mapc
     (lambda (frame)
       (mapc
        (lambda (window)
          (with-current-buffer (window-buffer window)
            (when hl-line-mode
              (make-local-variable 'face-remapping-alist)
              (let ((inactive (rassoc '(hl-line-inactive) face-remapping-alist)))
                (if (eq window (selected-window))
                    (progn
                      (setq dups (get-buffer-window-list nil nil 'visible))
                      (setq face-remapping-alist (delq inactive face-remapping-alist)))
                  (unless (or inactive (memq window dups))
                    (add-to-list 'face-remapping-alist '(hl-line hl-line-inactive))))))))
        (window-list frame)))
     (visible-frame-list))))

(add-hook 'buffer-list-update-hook #'toggle-active-window-highlighting)
```

Comment: See also function `walk-windows`, which you can use to iterate over the windows of visible frames, etc. (And +1 for `buffer-list-update-hook`, which gets called by `select-window`.)

Comment: +1 for this! Not so much for the hl-line stuff in specific, but I've been looking off and on for years to find a reliable way of shading the backgrounds of inactive windows in a frame. This works! Thanks!

Comment: Thank you, this is awesome!  Unfortunately, it seems to have problems when using `global-hl-line-mode`.  It seems that `global-hl-line-mode` doesn't load `hl-line-mode` for each buffer.  It uses an overlay instead of using the `hl-line` face.  I've been fiddling with it for a while with no luck.  Any suggestions?  Should I open a separate question?

Comment: You may want to use `window-state-change-hook` instead, because `buffer-list-update-hook` is call the buffer is changed.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `window-selection-change-functions`. By adding a function locally the function is called each time when the window showing that buffer has been selected/deselected (see the docstring for more info).

This can be used  to toggle `hl-line-face` face for the deft buffer:

```el
(defvar-local deft-hl-line-toggle-cookie+ nil)

(defun deft-toggle-hl-line-face+ (w)
  (cond ((eq (current-buffer) (get-buffer deft-buffer))
         (when deft-hl-line-toggle-cookie+
           (face-remap-remove-relative deft-hl-line-toggle-cookie+)))
        (t
         (with-current-buffer (get-buffer deft-buffer)
           (setq deft-hl-line-toggle-cookie+
                 (face-remap-add-relative
                  hl-line-face `(:inherit ,hl-line-face :background "gray")))))))

(defun deft-hl-line-toggle-setup+ ()
  (add-hook 'window-selection-change-functions
            'deft-toggle-hl-line-face+ nil t))

(add-hook 'deft-mode-hook 'deft-hl-line-toggle-setup+)
```

Comment: Thanks for answering this question despite it being so old! Your solution of using a buffer-local hook is much cleaner and less resource-intensive than previous solutions.