# How to highlight current line only in selected window?

Tags: highlighting, hl-line-mode

**Q**: is there a way to have `hl-line-mode` highlight the current line
  only in the selected window?

When I have multiple windows showing buffers with `hl-line-mode`
on, it is difficult to tell, at a glance, which window is
current.

I have the variable `cursor-in-non-selected-windows` set
to `nil` to show the cursor only in the current window, but that
visual cue is swamped by the highlighted lines in the windows.

Is there a similar setting to allow me to have `hl-line-mode` show
the highlighted line only in the current window?  Even better, is
there a way to give the highlighted lines a different face when
they're in inactive windows (analogous to `mode-line-inactive`)?

PS: yes, I can look at the mode line to tell which window is
active, but doing so takes my eyes away from what I'm doing and
breaks my concentration.

Comment: It seems that if you activate hl-line-mode with `global-hl-line-mode` (rather than calling hl-line-mode for each buffer) then only line the selected window is highlighted.

Comment: @IqbalAnsari: interesting!  Unfortunately, I only want to use `hl-line-mode` in a few buffer types (`occur`, `mu4e`, etc.).  I'll dig around in the source code when I get a moment.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can set `hl-line-sticky-flag` to `nil`

> hl-line-sticky-flag is a variable defined in `hl-line.el`.
>
> Non-nil means the HL-Line mode highlight appears in all windows.
>   Otherwise Hl-Line mode will highlight only in the selected
>   window.  Setting this variable takes effect the next time you use
>   the command `hl-line-mode` to turn Hl-Line mode on.
>
> This variable has no effect in Global Highlight Line mode.
>   For that, use `global-hl-line-sticky-flag`.

Comment: Ha! I didn't know this was an option, and ended up writing my own: http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/14658/780. I guess that approach has the benefit of letting you pick a different color for inactive windows, but I'll probably switch to this much simpler solution.