# How to use face-remap-set-base to substitute a face for another?

Tags: elisp, faces, functions

I'd like to locally remap a face to other custom face.  The docstring reads:

> `(face-remap-set-base FACE &rest SPECS)`
>
> Set the base remapping of `FACE` in the current buffer to `SPECS`. This
> causes the remappings specified by ‘`face-remap-add-relative`’ to apply
> on top of the face specification given by `SPECS`.
>
> The remaining arguments, `SPECS`, should form a list of faces. Each list
> element should be either a face name or a property list of face
> attribute/value pairs, like in a ‘face’ text property.

Armed with this knowledge, I tried:

```
(defface my/exceptional-face
  '((t (:background "red")))
  "My exceptional face.")
    
(face-remap-set-base 'font-lock-keyword-face '(my/exceptional-face))
```

In a Lisp buffer, `M-x eval-buffer RET`, I'd expect the keywords to show up with a red background.  However, this fails with:

```
(wrong-type-argument listp my/exceptional-face)
```

Indeed, the `face-remap-set-base` function reads:

```
 (defun face-remap-set-base (face &rest specs)
  (while (and (consp specs) (not (null (car specs))) (null (cdr specs)))
    (setq specs (car specs)))
  (if (or (null specs)
      (and (eq (car specs) face) (null (cdr specs)))) ; Error raised here
      ;; Set entry back to default
      (face-remap-reset-base face)
    ;; Set the base remapping
    ...snip...))
```

It thus seems that there's no way I can pass a single face to this function.  Using:

```
(face-remap-set-base 'font-lock-keyword-face '(my/exceptional-face nil))
```

…seems to work though.  Is that the expected behavior, or is this a bug?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the quoted list from around its elements. Just provide the elements (as an implicit list) as additional args to `face-remap-set-base`:

```lisp
(face-remap-set-base 'font-lock-keyword-face 'my/exceptional-face)
```

The code defining function `face-remap-set-base` binds its single `&rest` parameter `SPECS` to the *list* `(my/exceptional-face)`.

The doc says:

> The remaining arguments, `SPECS`, should **form a list of faces**.

What that means is what **`&rest`** means: provide faces individually as separate additional arguments. Don't provide an explicit *list* of faces as a single argument.

You provide any number of faces as additional actual arguments, and the function *receives*, as its single `&rest` argument `SPECS`, a *list* of those actual args that you passed.

See the Elisp manual, node [Argument List](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Argument-List.html), for an explanation of `&rest`.

In the code you provided the list `(my/exceptional-face)` that you passed resulted in the `&rest` parameter `SPECS` being bound to this list: `((my/exceptional-face))`.  Function `face-remap-set-base` figured that this was a list of one face, that face (or face spec) being the *list* `(my/exceptional-face)`. A face spec that's a list needs a certain form, and  `(my/exceptional-face)` doesn't have that form -- hence the error:

```
(wrong-type-argument listp my/exceptional-face)
```

See node [Defining Faces](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Defining-Faces.html) of the Elisp manual for the proper list form of a face spec.

---

Oddly enough, I don't find anywhere in the Elisp manual or the Eintr manual ([An Introduction to Programming in Emacs Lisp](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/)) where it is explained that passing multiple optional args to a function results in a single `&rest` list argument being received. But it's fundamental to Lisp (pretty much any Lisp, not just Elisp).

The [Common Lisp](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/Groups/AI/html/cltl/clm/node64.html) doc tells you this about a `&rest` parameter:

> all remaining arguments are **made into a list** for the `&rest` parameter

---

**However**, though all I said is I think true, the code I suggested that you use also fails.

I think there's a bug in the code of `face-remap-set-base`. I submitted bug report #[45264](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=45264).  We'll find out....

I note that there are zero uses of `face-remap-set-base` in the Emacs Lisp code. Perhaps it was never tested...

(Or perhaps I'm mistaken, and someone else will provide a correct answer.)

Comment: Thanks for the investigation Drew, appreciated!  I was aware of `&rest` arguments being passed as a list, although it seems that on SE, most people use these functions with a single list (e.g., [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/10033/change-mode-line-buffer-id-face-for-inactive-windows)).   Similarly, I've seen [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/14638) people using `(face-remap-set-base 'f1 (face-all-attributes 'f2))`, but I couldn't make this to work—is it because `face-remap`s expect a list rather than an alist?

Comment: It seems to me that `(elisp)Argument List` explains "that passing multiple optional args to a function results in a single &rest list argument being received" clearly enough (since 26.3 at minimum).  Specifically the example which states "any arguments after the first four are collected into a list and ‘e’ is bound to that list".