# How to make buffer name in mode-line be bold when its window is selected?

Tags: buffers, faces, mode-line

In Emacs, on the modeline: I would like the name of the currently focused buffer to be bold, but only when its window is selected.

My modeline looks something like this:

```
(setq mode-line-format
  (list "%&"
    " "
    (propertize "%b " 'face 'mode-line-buffer-id)
    "%p of %I"
    " "
    "[%l,%c]"
    'vc-mode
    " "
    'mode-line-modes
    ))
```

I would like "%b" (the name of the buffer) to be bold when its window is selected. I am totally new to Emacs Lisp. I thought setting the face to a variable that is changed by some "focus-in" hook would be the way to go (and possibly forcing the modeline to be redrawn).

I'm not sure what event I should hook in to. I know about focus-in-hook and focus-out-hook but those are for the frame.

Any hints are greatly appreciated.

Comment: The following link contains an example of how to display different things in the active window, versus the inactive window.  You can have bold font for the buffer-name in the active window, and just regular font for the buffer-name in the inactive window.  **Show something in active mode line instead of all mode lines**:  http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/26222/show-something-in-active-mode-line-instead-of-all-mode-lines  See also a related example of the same concept -- **Change mode-line-buffer-id face for inactive windows**:  http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/22682/2287

Answer (score 1):

Just *customize* face `mode-line-buffer-id`: **`M-x customize-face RET mode-line-buffer-id RET`**

In Customize, you can specify that the face's `Weight` attribute is `Bold`.

Set your edit changes, to see the effect.  Save your set changes, if you like the effect and want to have it in future Emacs sessions, by default.

Comment: Thank you. So what I'm trying to achieve is to change the face for the modeline corresponding to the currently focused buffer only. Am I missing something?

Comment: I see. What you mean is for the *selected window*. You can do that for the *whole* mode line, using face `mode-line` versus face `mode-line-inactive`. But to do it for just part of the mode line I think you will need to use an `:eval` form. Perhaps someone else will provide a simple answer. I'll delete my answer after a while - leaving it for now, for the comments.

Comment: Thanks. Could you elaborate on how I'd use eval, just for my education?

Comment: See the Elisp manual (`C-h i`), node [Mode Line Data](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Mode-Line-Data.html).

Comment: What confuses me is what exactly would I need to eval. How do I know if a buffer is active or not. What stores this info?

Comment: What you call "buffer is active" is that its window is the `selected-window`. Compare the values returned by `get-buffer-window` and`selected-window`.

Answer (score 1):

Here a solution (works only if buffers are different per windows)

```el
(defun toggle-mode-line-buffer-name-face (window)
  (with-current-buffer (window-buffer window)
    (if (eq (current-buffer) (window-buffer (selected-window)))
        (face-remap-reset-base 'mode-line-buffer-id)
      (face-remap-set-base 'mode-line-buffer-id '(:bold nil)))))
(add-hook 'buffer-list-update-hook (lambda () (walk-windows #'toggle-mode-line-buffer-name-face nil t)))
```